# I can't install a library with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I need a lib named "openupgradelib" in my env

I'm using Poetry to manage my env

I issued

```
poetry add openupgradelib
```

and it's properly written in the pyproject.toml file as

```
openupgradelib = "3.3.4"
```

BUT

when I issue

```
poetry install
```

I get

```
SolverProblemError

  Because project-blah depends on openupgradelib (3.3.4) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
```

How am I supposed to install this thing ?

Here's my pyproject-toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "project-blah"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
Babel = "2.6.0"
chardet = "3.0.4"
decorator = "4.3.0"
docutils = "0.14"
ebaysdk = "2.1.5"
freezegun = "0.3.15"
gevent = "20.9.0"
greenlet = "0.4.17"
html2text = "2018.1.9"
idna = "2.6"
Jinja2 = "2.11.2"
libsass = "0.17.0"
Mako = "1.0.7"
MarkupSafe = "1.1.0"
num2words = "0.5.6"
ofxparse = "0.19"
passlib = "1.7.1"
Pillow = "8.1.1"
polib = "1.1.0"
psutil = "5.6.6"
pydot = "1.4.1"
python-ldap = "3.1.0"
PyPDF2 = "1.26.0"
pyserial = "3.4"
python-dateutil = "2.7.3"
pytz = "2019.1"
pyusb = "1.0.2"
qrcode = "6.1"
reportlab = "3.5.55"
requests = "2.21.0"
zeep = "3.2.0"
python-stdnum = "1.8"
vobject = "0.9.6.1"
Werkzeug = "0.16.1"
XlsxWriter = "1.1.2"
xlwt = "1.3.*"
xlrd = "1.2.0"
psycopg2 = "^2.9.2"
cryptography = "^36.0.0"
codicefiscale = "^0.9"
openupgradelib = "3.3.4"


[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pydevd-odoo = "^1.1"
rope = "^0.22.0"
yapf = "^0.31.0"
pyflakes = "^2.4.0"
pylsp-mypy = "^0.5.2"
pylsp-rope = "^0.1.7"
python-lsp-server = {extras = ["yapf"], version = "^1.3.1"}


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Comment: The file seems fine, I removed the extra dependencies and installed `openupgradelib` with python3.9 without any problem.
Have you init the project with poetry init?
I'd try to remove everything, do a poetry init, then copy and paste the pyproject.toml and run poetry install.
Do you have any logs from poetry?