# I can't delete an poetry managed environment

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'd like to remove an environment (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73106694/i-cant-install-a-library-with-poetry) question)

when I issue

```
/progetti/project_blah$ poetry env remove ./.venv
```

I get

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./.venv: Permission denied

  EnvCommandError

  Command ./.venv -c "import sys; print('.'.join([str(s) for s in sys.version_info[:3]]))" errored with the following return code 126, and output: 
  

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:625 in remove
       621│                     shell=True,
       622│                 )
       623│             )
       624│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    →  625│             raise EnvCommandError(e)
       626│ 
       627│         python_version = Version.parse(python_version.strip())
       628│         minor = "{}.{}".format(python_version.major, python_version.minor)
       629│
```

What is this ?

Comment: You have a permissions error deleting .venv.  What does `ls -lh .venv` show?  Can you `rm -r .venv` [ **This will try to delete the dir .venv: be careful** ]?

In any case the problem here is in your env.  It could be user permissions, it could back actls, it could be somehing else.

Comment: Assuming you're `USER SCRUBBED` (maybe delete that comment if you don't want that to leak) then you aparently can delete it, so `rm` should work.

Comment: as for rm -r, I made a copy and the issued rm -r

$ rm -r .venv
$

Comment: and?  did it delete the dir?  if it did the venv is gone

Comment: yes, it deleted the folder .venv @2e0byo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the permission error, if you are here because you're unable to delete a locally created environment using poetry, you can refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2124). Basically, at the moment, you can't delete the local environment with the `poetry env remove <python>` command since it will return the `Environment does not exist` error. To overcome the issue you can delete the .venv folder as suggested also in the comment to the question or run `poetry env remove --all`. Be careful with this last command and use `poetry env list` before to check that there is only one environment (the locally created one) that is going to be deleted.

UPDATE: Problem seems to be fixed now. Check your version of poetry before.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to delete poetry env is to try something like this.

```
poetry env remove python3.10
```

or

```
% poetry env list                                                                                                                        
myenv-dL2uBROB-py3.10 (Activated)

% poetry env remove myenv-dL2uBROB-py3.10
```

Comment: I know that, that's what I did. My question is different